# Drupal 8 and Twig get language

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

i want to get the actual language which is chosen on a drupal 8 site in a node and start an if-request when e.g. the language is "en" to put out some content.

this is what i've already tried:

```
{% global language %}
{% set lang_name = language %}
{{ lang_name }}
```

and

```
{{ app.session.locale }}
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

but it doesnt work. 
can someone give me a hint how i can get the language via twig on drupal 8 or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your XXX.theme file:

```
function XXX_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $variables['language'] = $language;
}
```

in your node template:

```
{{ language }}
```

Comment: hej! thanks for your anwser. i have no ".theme"-file but i created one in the "themes" -> "custom" -> "xxx_theme" -> "xxx.theme". do i have to consider something else or is drupal adding this file automatically?

Comment: The "xxx" was meant as a placeholder for your theme name. Here's an example for a theme folder structure: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/folder-structure

Comment: i know. but do i have to do something that drupal register that new ".theme" file or will that happened automatically? because the language query above does not work for me at the moment. no language id or name is shown up in the node.

Comment: ahh i found the issue. i have to change the node to field because i ask the language in a field. :) "XXX_preprocess_field" thank you for your help!

Comment: glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set $language in php before using `{% global language %}` in twig:

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

Comment: hej spill, thank you for your anwser. do you know where i have to add this line?

Answer (score 1):

For language id you can use:

```
{{ language.getId() }}
```

For language name:

```
{{ language.getName() }}
```

For example:

```
{% if language.getId() == 'sr' %}
   <p>Zdravo svete!</p>
{% elseif language.getId() == 'hu' %}
   <p>Helló világ!</p>
{% else %}
   <p>Hello world!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For taxonomy terms you can do this:

`{{ term.langcode.langcode }}`